# GNURADIO: libfftw3f.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

I just installed gnuradio on my ubuntu 12.04. I tried running a simple wbfm receiver program that I got from online. When trying to execute the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Downloads/uhd_wbfm_receive.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gnuradio import analog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/analog/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from analog_swig import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/analog/analog_swig.py", line 26, in <module>
    _analog_swig = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/analog/analog_swig.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_analog_swig', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libfftw3f.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm quite new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `libfftw3-3` package, either using `sudo apt-get install` or by searching for it in Software Center.